# Where can I get the complete list of JNI function for NDK with Android Studio?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I follow this guide, Hello-JNI https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni

From internet sources, I found that the guide/sample//example/tutorial only provide the following example JNI function which is String :

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_test_helloandroidjni_MainActivity_getMsgFromJni(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

  return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello From Nani 2");//5. change return name
}
```

Above is the implementation, and its declaration is :

```
public native String getMsgFromJni();
```

I found there are another example instead of String but that program is for run in PC, not in Android.

I spent many hours but could not found any JNI function except String. I want JNI function for int, void, etc too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer this following link :

http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html

Answer (score 2):

Please find the below link which provides a complete listing of all the JNI functions. It also presents the exact layout of the JNI function table.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html

This will also useful
http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/index.html